# pass parametres to colorbox

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, parameters, colorbox

I am using a [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox).

```
<a class="publishpost" href="<?= base_url()."publish_ads/publishon/".$adds[$i]->getId()?>"></a>
                        <script>
                                $(document).ready(function(){ 
                                    $('.publishpost').colorbox({ width: '900px', height: '500px' });
                                });
                        </script>
```

I have this link that points to a codeigniter controller. I would like to access some variable from the view in which I load the colorbox. How can I do this. I thought about a form or maybe something with jquery but I still dont know how pass the parametres.

The values that I intend to pass as parametres are something like this for example:

```
<div class="external_wall_right_col_sub_ad_img"><img src="<?=$img?>" alt="small ad"></div>
```

I want to pass the $img variable to the colorbox.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question:

I use the data parameter of the colorbox which sends the data through post.

Answer (score 0):

Determining how you want the front-end to work is up to you--passing the data, however, I can help you with.

If you choose to use a form, you can access the form data in your controller that you are submitting to. From there you can define the $img variable as such:

```
$data['img'] = $this->input->post('input_name');
```

Then when you load your view, pass the data:

```
$this->load->view('view_name', $data);
```

This will pass all variables declared inside $data to your view. You can now access that variable in your view as you would like:

```
<img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="small ad">
```